# What is special about $2^{32}/\phi$ in cryptography?

Tags: cr.crypto-security

In the [Tiny Encryption Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm):

> Different multiples of a magic constant are used to prevent simple attacks based on the symmetry of the rounds. The magic constant, 2654435769 or 9E3779B9<sub>16</sub> is chosen to be $2^{32}/ \phi$, where ϕ is the golden ratio.

Which properties does $2^{32}/ \phi$ have that makes it useful in this context?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, such "magic" values have the following two properties:

1. They are somehow unique, and look random.
2. They can take part in algebraic operations repeatedly; i.e. even after applying some specific operation (say multiplication or exponentiation) many times, the "magic" value is still able to generate new values.

You may find a similar case in the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). Consider the following line:

`k[i] := floor(abs(sin(i + 1)) × (2 pow 32))`

Here, `sin(i + 1)` is meant to generate magic values; which are unique, random-looking, and can work for a lot of `i`'s. (Actually, `i` ranges in 0..63).

**Edit:** Reading the [original paper on TEA](http://www.cix.co.uk/~klockstone/tea.pdf), one understands that the answer given by "Steven Stadnicki" is correct. Note that the magic constant is name delta:

> A different multiple of delta is used in each round so that no bit of the multiple will not change frequently. We suspect the algorithm is **not very sensitive** to the value of delta and we merely need to avoid a bad value. It will be noted that delta turns out to be odd with truncation or nearest rounding, so no extra precautions are needed to ensure that all the digits of sum change.

Since only 32 multiples of delta is used (one per each round), it is not odd that the algorithm is not very sensitive to any specific delta. (See Steven Stadnicki's answer for more info.)

**Edit 2:** Incidentally, [MD4](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1320.txt) uses square roots of 2 (0x5a827999) and 3 (0x6ed9eba1) as "magic" constants in its operations. Section 5.4.4 of the book [Network Security: Private Communication in a Public World](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130460192) explains this well:

> To show that the designers didn't purposely choose a diabolical value of the constant, the constant is based on the square root of 2.

This explanation is the same as the point made below in a comment by Gilles.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Would 2^32/pi or 2^32/sqrt(2) have worked just as well, then?

Comment: @Tim: I guess so, but it is instrumental to double check the new magic numbers in the context of TEA internal operations.

Comment: Furthermore, a reason to choose a mathematical constant like 2^32/phi, rather than a randomly-generated value with acceptable properties, is to give a smidgen of confidence that this isn't a value chosen for additional unrevealed properties — a backdoor value.

Comment: @Gilles, indeed, they are even called "nothing up my sleeve number" for that reason, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number

Answer (score 12):

One reason that $\varphi$ makes a particularly useful 'magic number' in this context is that the multiples $n\varphi$ are guaranteed to be 'maximally far' from integers (this has to do with the lack of large terms in the continued fraction for $\varphi$), and thus the sequence $\{n\varphi\}$ (or more accurately, its initial segments) is more uniformly distributed mod 1 than the sequence $\{n\alpha\}$ for any other irrational $\alpha$.

To give an example: suppose we choose a magic constant $C_\pi = \lfloor {2^{32}/\pi}\rfloor = 1367130551$.  Then $(355C_\pi)\mod {2^{32}} = 41157$, an unexpectedly small result for such a small multiple of our magic constant.  By contrast, if we use the magic constant $C_\varphi = \lfloor {2^{32}/\varphi}\rfloor = 2654435769$, then the smallest $n$ for which $|(nC_\varphi)\mod {2^{32}}| \leq 2^{16}$ (abusing notation a bit) is $n=28657$.  In practice, this can conceivably lead to things like unexpectedly large correlations between the values $X_n$ and $X_{n+k}$ of a linear congruential random number generator for some smallish $k$; for the most part, though, it's folkloreish black magic, based more on the intuition that 'small multiples of this number being small mod $2^{32}$ will be bad' than on any specific theoretical results.

Comment: Interesting! I just didn't understand the last sentence quite well: What do you mean by "uniformly distributed mod 1"? For instance, the first 10 terms of {nφ} are [1.62, 3.24, 4.85, 6.47, 8.09, 9.71, 11.33, 12.94, 14.56, 16.18] (rounded to 2 decimal place).

Comment: Sadeq: 'mod 1' refers to the fractional part of the multiples - in this case these would be [.62, .24, .85, .47, .09, .71, .33, .94, .56, .18].  Equidistribution in the limit means that any subinterval [a, b] of [0, 1] contains the expected proportion (b-a) of these values; while it turns out that the fractional parts of the multiples of any irrational number are evenly distributed on [0, 1], those of the golden ratio approach that even distribution faster than any other number; they don't 'clump' on the unit interval.

Comment: $\pi$'s close approximation by 355/113, for instance, means that $113\pi$ will be much closer to an integer than it 'should be' and this shows up as a clustering of the fractional parts of its values; $\{(n+113)\pi\}$ will be exceptionally close to $\{n\pi\}$.  The golden ratio has no such good approximations, though; all of its approximations are 'maximally far' from it.  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#A_property_of_the_golden_ratio_.CF.86 covers this)

Comment: that's a very neat property of the golden ratio

Comment: Thanks for great description. It was really great! Do you have any comments on `k[i]`, as defined in MD5? (See my answer above.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't; - the only thing that comes to mind is that they may be chosen for approximate linear independence, since the functions $\sin(nx)$ are linearly independent over $x$ - but I don't know any reason to believe that this particular set of values should lead to relatively large values for $a_i$ in any linear relation $\Sigma a_i k[i] = 0$.

Comment: Sadeq: the result about $C_{\sqrt{5}}$ doesn't surprise me much; the statements about $\varphi$ essentially hold true for all of its 'cousins' $a+b\sqrt{5}$ since the terminal portion of their continued fraction is the same.  Are you sure about your result for $C_{\sqrt{3}}$? Since that's relatively prime to $2^{32}$, there should be _some_ $n$ for which $nC_{\sqrt{3}}$ is even congruent to $1\mod 2^{32}$!

Comment: @Steven: I find your claim that "those of the golden ratio approach that even distribution faster than any other number" very interesting. What is this phenomenon called? Where can I find a proof?

Comment: Below, I rewrite one of my comments above which had several typos. I deleted the original comment to reduce confusion...

Comment: I was (and am) quite interested in this answer, so I continued investigating it. For $C_{\sqrt 5} = \lfloor {2^{32}/\sqrt 5}\rfloor = 1920767766$, the smallest n for which $|(nC_{\sqrt 5})\mod {2^{32}}| \leq 2^{16}$ is 39603, which is quite larger than that of $C_\varphi$. The corresponding n's for $C_{\sqrt 2}$ and $C_{\sqrt 3}$ are 19601 and 18817, which are quite large (yet not as large as that of $C_\varphi$). Even worse: For $C_3 = \lfloor {2^{32}/ 3} \rfloor = 1431655765$, such an n does not exist!

Comment: @Steven: I wrote a very simple computer program to find the n for various C's, including $C_{\sqrt{3}}$. The program is in C#. You can download it from here: http://ifile.it/8yiqd5j. Note that $C_{\sqrt 3}$ is not relatively prime to $2^{32}$, but $C_{3}$ is!